# Flutter_newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, android-emulator, decoding

I am new to Flutter/coding. I am trying to work on my first project. I am following an online tutorial to create a weather app.
I followed all the instructions but when I am running the app, nothing shows up on my emulator.
There is an error on the Debug Console as below:

[image: Error on Debug Console]

I tried to google the error and found that I need to update the kotlin version in the buildscript in the build.gradle file. But in my build.gradle file there is no buildscript section. See below:

[image: build.gradle]

I again  googled for solution and I thought what if I add the code in my build.gradle file so I added the code with latest kotlin version 1.9.22 yet the error is still there.

Where am I going wrong.

I tried all solutions available in youtube and google. I have spent almost a day looking for it but no luck.

- I am running it on a windows 10, android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, Many times I have found that the latest Kotlin version is incompatible with the latest Flutter version.

Please, try to downgrade the version to `1.9.20` or less. Also try stable versions like `1.8.22`, ..., `1.7.10`, or others. Pick one that suits your project the best from here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details

and also from your screenshot, I saw that the section below is missing in your android/build.gradle file.

Add this and update your Kotlin extension version accordingly:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3' // 8.2.2 // 7.1.3 etc
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried downgrading to all the versions you mentioned here but it is still throwing me the same error. The surprising thing for me is that there  is no buildscript section in my build.gradle. I googled and added the script. I am not able to understand why. Any other solutions or any advice where I am going wrong.

Comment: Updated all yet the error is still there.

Comment: could you kindly tell me the distributionUrl from android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties?

Comment: This is the current distribution url    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

Comment: Answer updated. Could you try adding classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3' inside dependency block?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems they changed the way they are loading kotlin to a plugin mode.

What I've done is to open the `settings.gradle` file which is location under the `android` folder and changed the version of `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` to my desired version.

So the file now looks like

```
pluginManagement {
def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
}
settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }
 }

plugins {
  id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
  id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

Note: I had to restart my computer in order for this to work... Hope it helps.